# Find vectors with n-1 equal components

Tags: algorithm, math, vector, fortran

I have an unsorted set of *n*-dimensional vectors and, for each of the *n* dimensions in turn, I am looking for the subsets of vectors that differ in only this dimension's component. How can I do this efficiently?

Example:

```
[ (1,2,3), (1,3,3), (2,3,3), (1,2,5), (2,2,5), (2,3,4) ]

dim 3 variable: [ (1,2,3), (1,2,5) ] & [ (2,3,3), (2,3,4) ] 
dim 2 variable: [ (1,2,3), (1,3,3) ]
dim 1 variable: [ (1,3,3), (2,3,3) ] & [ (1,2,5), (2,2,5) ]
```

Thanks very much for your help!

**EDIT**

As requested in a comment I am now posting my buggy code:

```
recursive subroutine get_peaks_on_same_axis(indices, result, current_dim, look_at, last_dim, mode, upper, &
                                            num_groups, num_dim)

   ! Group the indices that denote the location of peaks within PEAK_INDICES which have n-1 dimensions in common.
   ! Eventually, RESULT will hold the groups of these peaks.
   ! e.g.: result(1,:) == (3,7,9)  <= peak_indices(3), peak_indices(7), and peak_indices(9) belong together

   integer, intent(in)    :: indices(:), current_dim, look_at, last_dim, mode, num_dim
   integer, intent(inout) :: upper(:), num_groups, result(:,:) ! in RESULT: each line holds a group of peaks
   integer                :: i, pos_on_axis, next_dim, aux(0:num_dim-1), stat
   integer, allocatable   :: num_peaks(:), groups(:,:)
   integer, save          :: slot

   if (mode.eq.0) slot = 1

   ! we're only writing to RESULT once group determination has been completed
   if (current_dim.eq.last_dim) then
      ! saving each column of 'groups' of the instance of the subroutine called one level further up 
      ! = > those are the peaks which have n-1 dimensions in common
      upper(slot)                = ubound(indices,1)
      result(slot,1:upper(slot)) = indices
      num_groups                 = slot ! after the final call it will contain the actual number of peak groups
      slot                       = slot + 1
      return
   end if

   aux(0:num_dim-2) = (/ (i,i = 2,num_dim) /)
   aux(num_dim-1)   = 1

   associate(peak_indices => public_spectra%intensity(look_at)%peak_indices,                                 &
             ndp => public_spectra%axes(look_at)%ax_set(current_dim)%num_data_points)

      ! potentially as many peaks as there are points in this dimension
      allocate(num_peaks(ndp), groups(ndp,ubound(indices,1)), stat=stat)
      if (stat.ne.0) call aloerr('spectrum_paraphernalia.f90',763)

      num_peaks(:) = 0

      ! POS_ON_AXIS: ppm value of the peak in dimension DIM, converted to an index on the axis
      ! GROUPS: peaks that have the same axis index in dimension DIM; line: index on axis; 
      do i=1,ubound(indices,1)
         pos_on_axis            = peak_indices(current_dim,indices(i))
         num_peaks(pos_on_axis) = num_peaks(pos_on_axis) + 1  ! num. of peaks that have this coordinate

         groups(pos_on_axis,num_peaks(pos_on_axis)) = indices(i)
      end do

      next_dim = aux(mod(current_dim+(num_dim-1),num_dim))

      do pos_on_axis=1,ubound(num_peaks,1)
         if (num_peaks(pos_on_axis).gt.0) then
            call get_peaks_on_same_axis(groups(pos_on_axis,1:num_peaks(pos_on_axis)), result, next_dim, look_at, last_dim, &
                                        1, upper, num_groups, num_dim)
         end if
      end do
   end associate
end subroutine
```

Comment: Homework ? what did you try to do so far ?

Comment: No, it's not homework, I need it for my actual work ;) I have written a recursive procedure that's not working properly and that, even though I thought of it myself, I haven't really got my head round, plus it's long-ish, so I thought posting it here would not help.

Comment: Are the vector's elements always integers? is their value bounded?

Comment: @RonTeller Yes, they will always be integers, and their values will be bounded, but the bounds will be determined at run time, and they will differ in the different dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the naive way?

Let's assume, you have `m` vectors with length `n`.

Then you have to compare all vectors with each other which results in `1/2*(m^2+m-) = O(m^2)` comparisons.

In each comparison you check your vectors element wise. If you find one difference you have to make sure, that there is no other difference. In best case, all vectors differ in the first 2 elements which is then 2 comparisons. The worst case is one or no difference which leads to `n` comparisons for the appropriate vectors.

If there is only one difference you can store its dimension, otherwise store a value like `0` or `-1`.